# Is there any way to remove comma after "group by" in siddhi query language?

Tags: sql, wso2-cep

I have below code in an execution plan.

```
from ocs_in#window.custom:ocs(20 sec,msisdn,package,rent,content)                        
select msisdn as msisdn,content as message                                                                      
group by msisdn                                                                                                     
insert into temp;
from temp select * insert into ocs_sms_out;
```

But, when I see the output, it has "commas" inside the message variable. Is there any way to remove those commas inside CEP itself such as group_concate in sql etc.?

I'm using CEP Version 3.1.0.

Answer (score 0):

No need to worry. It was not because of the group by class. It was caused by custom window function. After modifying it, commas were gone.